# Python - Unable to mock call for Inherited class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have this main class

```
def main(args):
    if type == train_pipeline_type:
        strategy = TrainPipelineStrategy()
    else:
        strategy = TestPipelineStrategy()
    for table in fetch_table_information_by_region(region):
        split_required = DataUtils.load_from_dict(table, "split_required")
        if split_required:
            strategy.split(spark=spark, table_name=table_name,
                           data_loc=filtered_data_location, partition_column=partition_column,
                           split_output_dir= split_output_dir)
            logger.info("Data Split for table : {} completed".format(table_name))
```

My TrainPipelineStrategy, and TestPipelineStrategy looks like this -

```
class PipelineTypeStrategy(object):

    def partition_data(self, x):
        # Something

    def prepare_split_data(self, y):
        # Something

    def write_split_data(self, z):
        # Something

    def split(self, p):
        # Something


class TrainPipelineStrategy(PipelineTypeStrategy):
    """"""


class TestPipelineStrategy(PipelineTypeStrategy):

    def write_split_data(self, y):
        # Something else
```

My test case - 
I need to test how many times split is called by mocking split functionality in main method.

Here is what i have tried -

```
@patch('module.PipelineTypeStrategy.TrainPipelineStrategy')
    def test_split_data_main_split_data_call_count(self, fake_train):
        fake_train_functions = mock.Mock()
        fake_train_functions.split.return_value = None
        fake_train.return_value = fake_train_functions
        test_args = ["", "--x=6"]
        SplitData.main(args=test_args)
        assert fake_train_functions.split.call_count == 10
```

When i try to run my test, it creates the mock but ultimately ends up calling the actual split function. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I cannot make much sense of your code but monkey patching is harder than it might look. It is easier if you pass what you want to mock as a parameter to the SUT.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with this code is that the way you set up the `patch` would be if `TrainPipelineStrategy` were a nested class of `PipelineTypeStrategy`, but `TrainPipelineStrategy` is a subclass of `PipelineTypeStrategy`.

Since `TrainPipelineStrategy` inherits from `PipelineTypeStrategy` it has access to `split` directly, so you can patch `split` without any reference to `PipelineTypeStrategy` (unless you specifically want to patch the version of `split` defined in `PipelineTypeStrategy`).

However, if you just want to mock the `split` method of the `PipelineTypeStrategy` class, you should use the `patch.object` decorator to mock just `split` instead of mocking the whole class as it's a bit more clean. Here's an example:

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch.object(TrainPipelineStrategy, 'split', return_value=None)
    def test_split_data_main_split_data_call_count(self, mock_split):
        test_args = ["", "--x=6"]
        SplitData.main(args=test_args)
        self.assertEqual(mock_split.call_count, 10)
```